# Determing system requirements to run a .NET application

Tags: .net, system-requirements

**How can I determine the minimum system requirement for a .NET application?**

I'd like to be able to determine what I should list as a minimum system requirements to run my application in terms of RAM, CPU, etc.

The application is written in C# and uses .NET 3.5 and DirectX9.

Is it all about **trial and error** (running it in various setups to see if it works), or are there **tools to do this**?

Comment: Hai Rahul will your application  be hosted on a dedicated server or shared hosting?

Comment: It is standalone, runs on PC only. No server or shared hosting. :)

Answer (score 1):

Usually you try it out on different hardware and keep note on how well it runs. From that you'll be able to deduce what is needed or recommended. I am not aware of other methods. Certainly you can't go around and say "Hey, this IL instruction here will totally need a Pentium 4".