# How to find the minimum system requirements for my winform application and outlook plugin

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, vsto, system-requirements

I have developed an outlook plugin and a winform application in C#.I want to determine the minimum system requirements for both of my applications.Please, let me know the steps for finding minimum system requirements,or if there is any tool out there which I can use for the purpose.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [Determining recommended system requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/893329/determining-recommended-system-requirements?rq=1) and [Determing system requirements to run a .NET application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865897/determing-system-requirements-to-run-a-net-application?rq=1)

Also, check AdminStudio tool, It will let you determine if your application will run on different OS versions.